# Android alpha animation: Staying in last animation frame when animation is completed

Tags: android, animation

I'm fading out an imageview with alpha animation. I'd like the image to stay transparent after the animation. Tried with different combinations of fillAfter and fillEnabled, no luck. How can this be achieved?

pom

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add an `Animation.AnimationListener` to the `Animation` via `setAnimationListener()`. In `onAnimationEnd()` of the listener, call `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` on the `ImageView`.

Comment: Not the best solution. See the answer by chris.

Comment: @ClassStacker: You are welcome to your opinion. `setFillAfter()` is rarely the right answer, because it does not really work the way one expects (e.g., `setFillAfter()` on a `TranslateAnimation` causes touch events to only work at the *old* location). For an alpha animation on a completely static UI, it may be survivable, but if anything much changes in that UI, I would not be the least bit surprised to see the alpha return to its original value. On Android 3.0+, you can just set the alpha property of the widget, of course.

Comment: I see; I wasn't aware of the `TranslateAnimation` problem. Good to konw! Great you provided this motivation for your solution.

Answer (score 16):

setting fillEnabled and fillAfter to true always works for me.

```
anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.3f, 1.0f);
anim.setDuration(500);
anim.setFillEnabled(true);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
<view>.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: I second that. Can also be achieved in XML alone.

Comment: nice! Thanks, brother. :)